# How to obtain a vector with the indexes of the elements given in a combination?

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, combinations

I have a vector that stores unique area values. I am using a *for* loop to generate an array with the sum of every possible combination of these areas, as shown below:

```
A_values=[155 143 193.5 233.25 419.7 351.9 256.8 1054.9 997.5 997.5 726.2 73.5 66.8 62 82.5]

comb_sums=[];
indexes=[];
    for x=1:length(A_values)
      comb_sums=[comb_sums;
                sum(combntns(A_values,x),2)];
    end
```

Now I would like to obtain the indexes of the elements given in every combination. For example, if some of the possible given combinations had been [143], [726.2 66.8] and [155 419.7 256.8], the code would give me an array like this:

```
indexes=[ 2 0 0 0; 
          11 13 0 0;
          1 5 7 0];
```

The array that I get from the *for* loop is obviously much bigger than the example given in the *indexes* variable above, so *indexes* would give me a much bigger array too.

Comment: How do you know that it would have 4 columns for `indexes`? Wouldn't that change at each iteration? For the final iteration the # of cols would be `length(A_Values)`.

Comment: Yes, you are right! The number of columns would be length(A_values). I just wanted to give a short example on the output I am looking for and didnt notice that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array of indices and use `combntns` on it, just you like did on `A_values` -

```
nA = numel(A_values)
for k1 = 1:nA
    comb_out = combntns([1:nA],k1);
    indexes = [comb_out zeros(size(comb_out,1),nA - size(comb_out,2))]
end
```

---

If you would like to store up `indexes` from each iteration into a huge array named `indexes_all` instead, you can pre-calculate the sizes of `indexes` for each iteration and use them to pre-allocate for `indexes_all`. The code would be -

```
%// Number of A_values to be used at various places in the code
nA = numel(A_values);

%// Get number of rows to be produced at each iteration
nrows = arrayfun(@(x) factorial(nA)/(factorial(x)*factorial(nA-x)),1:nA);

%// Preallocate with zeros as also needed in the desired output
indexes_all = zeros(sum(nrows),nA); 

off1 = 1; %// row-offset
for k1 = 1:nA
    comb_out = combntns(1:nA,k1); %// combntns on array of indices
    indexes_all(off1:off1+nrows(k1)-1,1:size(comb_out,2)) = comb_out; %// Store
    off1 = off1+nrows(k1); %// Update row-offset for next set of combinations
end
```

Comment: it seems to be still missing something. The # of rows for the output should be the total number of all possible combinations found. However your code seems to give only the last vector of the array.

Comment: @HelP Did you check out the new approach to get all indexes with `indexes_all`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I hadn't seen it! That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @HelP If this solution has adequately answered what you were after, please consider accepting it by clicking on the **check mark** at the top-left side of the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Comment: I'm trying to use the same method in a similar situation, but now nA=10252, so nrows gives me an array of NaNs. Do you know why this happens and how to solve it? 

I get the following error when I try to preallocate with zeros:
    `??? Error using ==> zeros`
    `NaN and Inf not allowed.`

Comment: @HelP I think there's an upper limit to it that you are exceeding there with such a huge number.